# How does compiler deduce return type from this lambda expression?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, boost, function-declaration

I am creating a web-socket server in C++ with Boost library. My starting point was a Boost example from this [site](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/beast/example/websocket/server/async/websocket_server_async.cpp).
I have a question with this part of code in the `on_run` method:

```
 ws_.set_option(websocket::stream_base::decorator(
            [](websocket::response_type& res)
            {
                res.set(http::field::server,
                    std::string(BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING) +
                        " websocket-server-async");
            }));
```

As it can seen, `ws_.set_option` takes a `websocket::stream_base::decorator` as a parameter and this parameter is created by a lambda expression, which takes a `Decorator&&` type variable as a parameter according to this [site](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/ref/boost__beast__websocket__stream_base__decorator/decorator/overload2.html).

How does the lambda expression know, it should return a `Decorator&&`, when there is no trailing-return-type or return statement in the lambda expression?
Last, but no least, where does the `websocket::response_type &res` come from? There is no `()`  including this parameter after the lambda body.

Comment: the lambda has `void` return type

Comment: [The `decorator` constructor](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/ref/boost__beast__websocket__stream_base__decorator/decorator/overload2.html) takes a callable object as an argument. This callable object is not used to create the `decorator` object itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`websocket::stream_base::decorator` is a template function with one template type parameter.

```
template<class Decorator>
decorator( Decorator&& f );
```

In this call

```
ws_.set_option(websocket::stream_base::decorator(
        [](websocket::response_type& res)
        {
            res.set(http::field::server,
                std::string(BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING) +
                    " websocket-server-async");
        }));
```

the function is called accepting the lambda expression

```
[](websocket::response_type& res)
        {
            res.set(http::field::server,
                std::string(BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING) +
                    " websocket-server-async");
        }
```

as its template argument. The lambda expression has by default the return type `void` because there is no return statement in the lambda expression.

> How does the lambda expression know, it should return a Decorator&&

It is the lambda expression itself is used as an argument for the declared function template parameter  `Decorator&&`.

Answer (score 1):

`websocket::stream_base::decorator(...` calls the constructor of `decorator`. This constructor apparently takes a callable as parameter. The lamdba that is passed has no return. Its return type is `void`.

See here (link by Some programmer dudes comment): https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/ref/boost__beast__websocket__stream_base__decorator/decorator/overload2.html.